# How do you encode SHA-256 twice?

Tags: hash, cryptography

Very simply, how does one get the "second round" below?

> hello
>   2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824 (first round of sha-256)
>   9595c9df90075148eb06860365df33584b75bff782a510c6cd4883a419833d50 (second round of sha-256)

I went to an online hash calculator, put in "hello", got the first round, and then took that hash and put it into the calculator and got a different result than the second round. How does it do it twice then?

Comment: If you just copy/pasted the first result, most likely it had one or more space characters appeneded to the end of it, which will completely throw off the hash.

Comment: I just typed it in to see if it would change, and it didn't. I keep getting d7914fe546b684688bb95f4f888a92dfc680603a75f23eb823658031fff766d9

Comment: Is this quote I pulled incorrect theN?

Comment: should it hash the raw bytes, not the base64 encoded bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pasted the first hash output back into the hash calculator for a second round, you were hashing it as an ASCII string of letters and numbers, not as the actual sequence of bytes expressed by those hex numbers.  In other words, the first byte of the string you plug into the hash calculator needs to actually be 0x2C, not 0x32 (which is the ASCII value of the character '2' at the beginning of "2cf2...")

Comment: Ok, then my logic is correct. It hashes the output of the first hash. Thanks so much.

Comment: @joslinm, of course.  SHA doesn't care if the input you give it happens to be the output of another invocation of SHA.  It's just bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n hello | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl dgst -sha256
```